# BlueJ installed editor window not opened

Tags: openjdk

I've just installed BlueJ .deb version over Ubuntu 20.04. Installed successfully and created new project also. But it doesn't open editor when I double clicked the java source file. I have openjdk(14) and openjfx(11) installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here. It seems that openjfx is not compatible with bluej and others apps. [bug openjfx](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx/+bug/1799946)

So I installed the "generic version" of bluej and the recommended openjfx lib:
[Install bluej:](https://www.bluej.org/generic-installation-instructions.html)

- Download the openjfx from [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) Unpack its "lib" dir to
  `/usr/shares/openjfx11` (or another name)
- Start the installation of    bluej with `java -jar path/to/bluej.jar`
- In the opened dialog set the correct jfx path as mentioned above..